# Only Single GitLab CI Runner Building

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I recently installed GitLab and am attempting to use GitLab CI. I successfully enabled GitLab CI in my GitLab Server and successfully installed a CI Runner (on Windows, if this is relevant). I enabled a project for the Windows CI Runner and when I commit to the repository the runner is executed and I can see the builds.

I installed a second CI Runner (on Debian) following the documentation. I can see the Debian CI Runner is registered, along with the Windows CI Runner. The Debian CI Runner has the same project assigned to it. However, when I commit to the repository only the Windows CI Runner is executed, the Debian CI Runner is not attempting to build.

What mistake have I made or what additional configuration is there to enable this? I have already tried re-registering the Debian CI Runner with no success.

---

**Update 1:** The Debian CI Runner is now executing but the Windows CI Runner is not. It seems to select only a single runner.

**Update 2:** Upgraded to 'GitLab CI 7.14.1 2dee1b3' but same behaviour persists.

**Update 3:** Added a third runner on a Scientific Linux machine. It is registered and assigned the project but only a single runner executes (currently the Debian CI Runner).

---

<strike>GitLab CI 7.12.0 e96755c</strike>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a build for gitlab CI is triggered, it will execute jobs listed in the .gitlab-ci.yml file. Think of these jobs as independent, concurrent steps in your build. These jobs are executed by any available runner capable of completing that job. However, where I think you're getting tripped up is that a job will *only be completed once, and by the first available runner*. Think of the runners as a pool of resources, not as build steps. Having multiple runners allows you to execute jobs in parallel.

If you have one job that you want to have executed each time by each runner, try using tags. E.g.:

```
job1:
  tags:
    - windows
  script:
    - job command 1
    - job command 2

job2:
  tags:
    - debian
  script:
    - job command 1
    - job command 2
```

Where `job command 1` and `job command 2`, etc., are the steps you'd like your job to perform, and `windows` and `debian` are the tags that you'll assign to your runners. Basically you're just creating identical jobs with different tags, one job for each runner. Then, you need to make sure each runner has the tag that you specify for its job. You can do this by editing the runner in gitlab CI.

1. Go to Runners
2. Scroll down to "Runners activated for this project"
3. Click on the edit symbol
4. Add the tag to the runner
5. Click Save

[See the gitlab YAML readme for more on tags](http://doc.gitlab.com/ci/yaml/README.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Thanks again, this does what I need.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked for you! We have a similar issue, testing our build against different environments. So far I haven't found a better way to do this that avoids the duplication of the jobs.

Comment: It appears that you can actually specify multiple ``tags`` sections under one job. For example like shown here: https://gist.github.com/dom96/1b393c507b62868ea7fc0c6d1d641a80

Answer (score 0):

It’s distributed as source code or as a simple omnibus package to install on one of the supported Linux distributions. However, there are some areas where that makes it quite hard to use, and one of it is:

- The runner can only run one concurrent at a time. If you want to run more either you set up a new server or create an additional user to build the jobs.

**Try to use Docker.**

What is important that every time your project is built it will be run in clean environment without any leftovers from previous builds. With few simple commands you don’t have to install any dependencies, because Docker will download everything required to run your tests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not attempting to run multiple builds on a single runner. I have mutiple runners on different machines.